# MySql Search query--keyword pendrive but in db it is Pen Drive so need query to display record

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

In search if user keyword is: **Pendrive**

And in my database it is: **Pen Drive**

We need to show pen drive ..for this can anyone please help me in writing query. From yesterday I am stuck.

I have tried below query but **its not working :**

```
Select cat_name 
from category 
where  cat_name LIKE '%pendrive%'
```

It is showing 0 records

I need a query which displays "Pen Drive"

Thanks in advance

Comment: kapil & fullstack--- As of now i have combied both of ur queries      $skey='samsungj2';    SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE (REPLACE(category_name , ' ','%') LIKE REPLACE('%$skey%',' ','%') )
or  (REPLACE(category_name, ' ','') LIKE REPLACE('%$skey%', ' ',''));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select cat_name 
from category 
where  REPLACE(cat_name, ' ','') LIKE REPLACE('%Pendrive%', ' ','')
```

Comment: I have executed ur query -----o/p:MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0190 seconds.)

Comment: you can see my solution :P

Comment: trim just removes leading and trailing spaces, it wont remove spaces between words , so this also wont work

Comment: hmmmm yes i have tried using match,replace,concat keywords but non of them worked

Comment: since last three days i was browsing for solution .....but i dint got o/p.so i decided post asking question online like  this was my first time ...u helped me a lot thanqq once again

Comment: now again i got another challege is   if a product in our database is Samsung galaxy j2 and if user search with samsung j2 we need to display Samsung galaxy j2   Please help me with this also........my belief is u can help me with this also

Comment: Select cat_name 
from category WHERE MATCH(cat_name) AGAINST ('samsung j2' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) --- try this one

Comment: no did not work for me but thanks again for helping me

Comment: Kapil gave a solution

Comment: but query which u given satisfied pendrive:: Select category_name from category where REPLACE(category_name, ' ','') LIKE REPLACE('%n driv%', ' ','') but for samsung :SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE REPLACE(category_name , ' ','%') LIKE REPLACE('%samsung j2%',' ','%'); this is working fine ......Now need aa single query which satisfies both cases

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE REPLACE(cat_name , ' ','') LIKE '%pendrive%'
```

it works..

Edit : this works for both types of input i.e. with and without spaces

```
SELECT cat_name 
FROM category
WHERE REPLACE(cat_name , ' ','') LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE('your keyword here',' ','%'),'%');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding but got error like this        i am using phpmyadmin                                   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: can you pls paste your actual query which you are executing

Comment: Select category_name 
from category
where replace(category_name , ' ','') LIKE CONCAT('%',replace('pendrive',' ','%'),'%');                                    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3

Comment: If i use these words Replace ,Match...than it is showing error

Comment: ohhhh dont know much about mariadb, but its working in mysql 5.6.28

Comment: mysql version??

Comment: Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
    Server type: MariaDB
    Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@localhost
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: you are running "Select category_name from category where limit 0,25;"

Comment: the query which i ececuted is ::::::;;Select category_name from category where replace(category_name , ' ','') LIKE CONCAT('%',replace('pendrive',' ','%'),'%');            this was suggested by u

Comment: see the error you are getting, that is some else query

Comment: thanq @kapil for trying to help me

Comment: Full stack given solution ......now again i got another challege is if a product in our database is Samsung galaxy j2 and if user search with samsung j2 we need to display Samsung galaxy j2 ...can u Please help me with this

Comment: SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE REPLACE(cat_name , ' ','%') LIKE REPLACE('%samsung j2%',' ','%');

Comment: query which fullstack given satisfied pendrive::  Select category_name 
from category 
where  REPLACE(category_name, ' ','') LIKE REPLACE('%n driv%', ' ','')  but for samsung :SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE REPLACE(category_name , ' ','%') LIKE REPLACE('%samsung j2%',' ','%'); this is working fine ......Now need aa single query which satisfies both cases